# Question about certain morphism between affine spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let the map $\varphi:\mathbb{A}^2\to\mathbb{A}^4$ is given by

$$(x,y)\mapsto(x, xy, y(y-1), y^2(y-1)).$$

How to find the system of equations, which defines the image of $\varphi$?

If we denote $u=x$, $v=xy$, $w=y(y-1)$, $t=y^2(y-1)$ then we have the relations 
$$ut=vw,\,\,v(v-u)=u^2w,$$
but it seems that it is not enough.

Next, denote $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $B=\mathbb{C}[x, xy, y(y-1), y^2(y-1)]$. Then $A=B+yB$ which shows that $\varphi$ is a finite morphism.

How to show that $\varphi$ is birational and $\text{Im}(\varphi)$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^4$ but not normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting a partial answer since it's too long for the comment box.

I don't know enough to answer the rest of your questions, but I believe the equation you are missing to define the image is $(t-w)t=w^3$. Your equations are sufficient if $x\ne 0$, but if $x=0$, then we need this equation. Then if $w=0$, then $t^2=0$ so $t=0$, then this point is given by $(x,y)=(0,0)$. If $w\ne 0$, then let $y=t/w$, and by the equation $w=y(y-1)$. Similarly, $y^2(y-1)=\frac{t^2}{w^2}(\frac{t}{w}-1)$, but $t^2=w^3+tw$, so $y^2(y-1)=(w+\frac{t}{w})(\frac{t}{w}-1)=\frac{t^2}{w^2}-\frac{t}{w}+t-w=w+\frac{t}{w}-\frac{t}{w}+t-w=t$. So $(x,y)=(0,\frac{t}{w})$ gives this point.

Therefore the two equations above together with this equation give the image of the map.